# Can I run/access localhost server thru ip and subnet?

Tags: webserver, ip, subnet

Is it possible for me to run a webserver on my computer (shared ip) and access it remotely using my ip + subnet or at least some way that doesn't involve having the IT guys make changes to the machine(s) currently running our virtual servers and/or routing our subnet?

**Rationale:**
I'm on a computer at work, and I'm making changes to a plugin for Google Website Optimizer. I want GWO to be able to access localhost (i.e. my development environment) so that I don't have to deploy every change to the production server while I'm feeling out the system. (lots of changes; tedious deployment takes up most of the time)

I can't just supply my IP to GWO because that points to our production server (all of our computers at work are on the same IP).  If I could construct a URI that points just to my computer, then I suppose I could let GWO view a page on my development environment and interact therewith.

Not only would achieving this purpose be helpful in present circumstances, but it would aid me immensely in that I could let my boss look at what I've got in dev, from his own machine, at his leisure, without deploying changes to production.

Comment: What do you mean by "my computer (shared ip)"? And what do you mean by "remotely"? And what's any of that got to do with the administration of virtual servers?

Comment: Just added 'Rationale' above, to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Google Website Optimizer, or how/where a plugin for it that you might write would be executed. So I'm going to summarize what I understand about your problem (including some guesses) and go from there, please correct me if I'm wrong.

- Your company has one public IP address.
- Your workstation and all the hosts on your network are source NAT'ed to the internet.
- Port 80 (http) on your public IP address is destination NAT'ed to your production webserver which is hosted as a virtual machine.
- You have a development webserver that is hosted on your workstation.
- You have reservations about involving your "IT guys" to making routing or system admin changes.
- You want your development environment to be accessible from the internet.

First up (assuming everything above is correct):
`access it remotely using my ip + subnet` - No. Not possible.

Second up:
`I could let my boss look at what I've got in dev` - Easy, get him to point his browser at your workstation's IP address on your internal network.

Possible solutions for remotely accessible:

1. Talk to your "IT guys" about getting your dev environment made externally accessible.
2. Use name-based virtual hosts on your production webserver. Requires setting up a DNS record for the dev site (e.g. `dev.your-company`) and pointing it to your company's IP address. If SSL is in use this is harder to achieve. You could then:

   - Proxy requests for a different site name to your workstation (readily achievable with apache)..  or
   - Host your development environment on your production server
3. Proxy a particular URL path to your workstation. (e.g. `/dev/`)
4. Get an unused port (e.g. 8080) on your public IP destination NAT'ed to port 80 on your workstation.  Your dev environment URL might then be `http://www.your-company:8080/`